# How can I run Drools with no process on BPMS?

Tags: jboss, drools, redhat, business-process-management

I hope someone can help me. I am using the REST API suggested by official documentation on RedHat BPMS to access BPMS. My question is, how can I run rools (.DRL) and access them without starting a bpm process ? What I am trying to do is use the BPMS as a rule repository. I tried with S-RAMP with no success until now and I have no option of not using BPMS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BPMS execution environment was designed around the JBPM use cases, in future version we will deliver a drools specific execution server as well for drools use cases. For now you can try by executing some rules triggered by a process, what is your limitation on starting bpm processes?

Comment: My limitation is the perfomance. I would like to try running the rules on my side instead of the server. If I could somehow get the rules from BPMS would be great ! By now the only way I have of running rules is as you said, building some process with them on it ! Thanks for the help !

Comment: Creating a simple rule service should be possible. I mean, you will end up with a service to maintain but it will fit your needs. Look at the drools repository for some examples that are doing what you need.

Comment: I have figured out a way to import artifacts from S-Ramp repository and I am trying this way for now but anyway thaks for your help !